# Getting Exception from Google Cloud endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cordova, google-cloud-endpoints

```
    We have developed mobile application by using phonegap. We are connecting to the backend by using Google Cloud endpoints. We have written our api's at server side
    using java(Google App engine) to get the data. Every thing was working fine but suddenly i got the following exception:
```

Code Snippet:
        com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: cause={0}
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.veersoft.services.api.ListTenantAPI.listTenant(ListTenantAPI.java:49)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
            at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
            at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
            at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:142)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at com.veersoft.filter.ResetUserMessagesAndErrorsFilter.doFilter(ResetUserMessagesAndErrorsFilter.java:30)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
            at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
            at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
            at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
            at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
            at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
            at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
            at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

```
    E 2014-10-03 10:00:48.322

    com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.veersoft.services.api.ListTenantAPI.listTenant(ListTenantAPI.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:142)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.veersoft.filter.ResetUserMessagesAndErrorsFilter.doFilter(ResetUserMessagesAndErrorsFilter.java:30)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The data is coming fine after some time but i do not know why the above exception comes suddenly, I am worrying that it might be occur in the future? I have gone through my api, every thing is fine.
Could any body please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show the related code?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your stack trace, it's clear that your Endpoints API method (`com.veersoft.services.api.ListTenantAPI.listTenant`) is where the null pointer exception (NPE) occurs. Without seeing your code, we can't know what the exact NPE is, but the stack trace does give you the line number, so you can inspect `ListTenantAPI.java` at line 49 to figure out what's happening.

You need to look into your client code and possibly into phonegap to figure out why `listTenant()` is having a NPE thrown.